# Create View with Model and List<Model>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project model and a technology model.  There can be multiple technologies in one project.  There will be a limited amount of technology objects, around 5-10, that will be used across an unlimited amount of projects.  I thought of keeping the technology items in an enum or just as constant variables, but I want the ability to add or edit down the road, so I figured I would put them in a table.

I tend to get hung up when dealing with lists.  I want to be able to create a single project, and in the same view check a checkbox for the technology that was used on the project (ex. HTML5 or CSS3).  I am not able to get a list of technologies to show up in the view for me to mark as checked for the particular project.

**Project Class:**

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }        
}
```

**Technology Class:**

```
public class Technology
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ProjectTechnologyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } 
    public Project Projects { get; set; }

    public ProjectTechnologyViewModel()
    {
        Projects = new Project();
    }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
public class NovaDB : DbContext
{
    public NovaDB(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CreateProject()
{

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateProject(ProjectTechnologyViewModel viewModel)
{
    var proj = new Project();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        proj.LaunchDate = viewModel.Projects.LaunchDate;
        proj.ProjectType = viewModel.Projects.ProjectType;
        proj.ServiceId = viewModel.Projects.ServiceId;
        proj.ShowInOurWork = viewModel.Projects.ShowInOurWork;
        proj.Website = proj.Website;

        proj.Technologies = new List<Technology>();

        foreach (var t in viewModel.Technologies)
        {
            proj.Technologies.Add(new Technology()
            {
                Name = t.Name,
                FAClassName = t.FAClassName,
                IsActive = t.IsActive,
            });
        }

        _db.Projects.AddOrUpdate(proj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(proj);
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Project</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Projects.Website, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Projects.Website, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Projects.Website, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Technologies.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.Technologies[i].)
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Image of View:**
[image: I cannot access the Technology properties such as isActive or name]

Comment: I'd reconsider the AddOrUpdate -- that's primarily for migrations: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to change a few models and I added a table to map the two models.  I decided to save the "link" between the Project & Technology models in a shared table called ProjectTechnologyMap.  For the project I create, I insert a record with the project Id and the Technology Id.  The project Id stays constant and there are multiple technology Ids, depending on how many are selected in the view.  I also save my project details to the project table.  I do not save anything to the technology table as it is static (I do not create technologies on my Create Project View).

Here is my solution that worked:

**Models:**

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTechnologyMap
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ProjectTechnologyViewModel
{
    public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } 
    public Project Projects { get; set; }
    public ProjectTechnologyMap ProjectTechnologyMapping { get; set; }

    public ProjectTechnologyViewModel()
    {
        Projects = new Project();
        ProjectTechnologyMapping = new ProjectTechnologyMap();

    }
}
```

**DB Context:**

```
public class NovaDB : DbContext
{
    public NovaDB(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectTechnologyMap> ProjectTechnologyMappings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var technologies = from t in _db.Technologies
                               orderby t.Name
                               where t.IsActive
                               select t;

            var viewModel = new ProjectTechnologyViewModel();
            viewModel.Technologies = technologies.ToList();

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ProjectTechnologyViewModel viewModel)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var proj = new Project
                {
                    LaunchDate = viewModel.Projects.LaunchDate,
                    ProjectType = viewModel.Projects.ProjectType,
                    ServiceId = viewModel.Projects.ServiceId,
                    ShowInOurWork = viewModel.Projects.ShowInOurWork,
                    Website = viewModel.Projects.Website
                };

                _db.Projects.AddOrUpdate(proj);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                var map = new ProjectTechnologyMap();

                foreach (var item in viewModel.Technologies)
                {
                    if (item.UsedInProject)
                    {
                        map.TechnologyId = item.Id;
                        map.ProjectId = proj.Id;
                        _db.ProjectTechnologyMappings.Add(map);
                        _db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
        }
```

**Loop in my View to handle the list of technologies:**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Technologies.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Technologies[i].Name, Model.Technologies[i].Name, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Technologies[i].UsedInProject)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Technologies[i].Id)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox is for the `IsActive` property of the Technology, right? So, you can do this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Technologies.ToList()[i].IsActive) @Model.Technologies.ToList()[i].Name
```

You also need to instantiate your ViewModel and send it to your view in your GET action, like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateProject()
{
    var model = new ProjectTechnologyViewModel();
    model.Project = new Project();
    model.Technologies = new List<Technology>();

    return View(model);
}
```

Also, don't instantiate the properties in your ViewModel. Do that in your controller (see above):

```
public class ProjectTechnologyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } 
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but it does not allow it...."Cannot apply indexing to [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<Technology>'

Comment: The Model.Technologies.Count() returns error "Object ref not set to an instance of an object".  Should I be passing a list of the technologies to this view so it can access it?

Comment: There should be something wrong in your GET action. You have posted a lot of code, except the one that really matters. Post your GET action.

Comment: The Get action is the first thing listed under controller.

Comment: @coggicc, well, then, of course you get the error. You're not passing a model to your view. Your model is empty. See the second update.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you referring to a `IEnumerable` as an array?
this - `someIEnumerable[0]` will not be compiled.
Why don't you use foreach?

```
foreach(var i in Model.Technologies){
   var a =  i.Website;
}
```

Comment: This will have problem with model binding.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need a table to store the Technologies associated with a Project, (say `ProjectTechnlogies`) that will include FK fields to the Project `ID` field and the Technology `ID` field.

Then you will need view models to represent what your wanting to edit in the view

```
public class TechnologyVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // for binding to a checkbox
}
public class ProjectVM
{
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TechnologyVM> Technologies { get; set; }
}
```

and your GET method would be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProjectVM model = new ProjectVM
    {
        Technologies = _db.Technologies.Where(t => t.IsActive).Select(t => new TechnologyVM
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Note I am assuming here that your `IsActive` property means that if the value is `false` its now an obsolete technology (it may have been assigned to previous Projects) and that you don't want to allow to to be selected in the view when creating a new Project.

Then create an `EditorTemplate` (partial) for `TechnologyVM` in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TechnologyVM.cshtml` (note the name of the file must match the name of the class)

```
@model TechnologyVM
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name) // if you want this value to be posted
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSelected, Model.Name)
</div>
```

and the main view will be

```
@model ProjectVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Website)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Technologies)
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method will correctly generate the html for each Technology

Finally you POST method will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProjectVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    Project project = new Project
    {
        Website = model.Website,
        // ... other properties of Project
    }
    _db.Projects.Add(project);
    _db.SaveChanges(); // The Project's Id property has now been set
    IEnumerable<int> selectedTechnologies = model.Where(t => t.IsSelected).Select(t => t.Id);
    foreach(int ID in selectedTechnologies)
    {
        ProjectTechnology technology = new ProjectTechnology
        { 
          ProjectId = project.Id,
          Technology = ID
        };
        _db.ProjectTechnologies.Add(technology);
    }
    _db.SaveChanges(); // save the project technologies
    // redirect
}
```